# How to enable feature in Project Web App site collection ?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Am trying to enable feature in the Project Web App. Actually, am trying to re deploy workflow .wsp file which has same name and same Guid value as earlier. I uninstalled the solution from "Manage Farm Solution".

When am trying to add and deploy the solution, it's failing.

Here are the commands I have used so far :

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath C:\DeployPSS\Workflow.wsp
Install-SPSolution –Identity Workflow.wsp –GacDeployment
Enable-SPFeature -Identity Workflow Feature1 -Url http://xyz/pwa
```

Can anyone let me know the procedure to redeploy the solution to farm which has same name and same Guid value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be problem with wsp deployment.

If the previously deployed wsp is available you have to retract and delete it in the following location

Central Administration -> Click on the manage farm solutions in farm management -> 
Check the status of your wsp.

Retract and delete using the following steps

1) Click on the wsp name.

2) Click on the retract solution.

3) Choose when to retract the solution as now.

4) Click Ok button and wait for a few seconds and then refresh the page. Now the status will be ‘not deployed’.

5) Once again click on the wsp name and status will be ‘not deployed’

6) Click on ‘remove solution’.

Now if you are using the workflow wsp you can deploy and install it using the following steps

Open sharepoint management shell

Start -> Programs -> Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products -> SharePoint 2010 Management Shell(rt click and run as administrator)

Add wsp using this in the management shell

Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "E:\WSP Backup\test.wsp"

Install the added wsp using this in management shell

Install-SPSolution -Identity test.wsp –GACDeployment

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity "Workflow Feature1" -Url http://xyz/pwa
```

If name of the feature contains blank space, it should be in commas.

If this does not work, please provide detailed error that you are getting.